# selenium/phpunit fails when i can see the text in the screenshot

Tags: selenium, phpunit

i am using selenium with phpunit to test some of my web stuff but it seems to fail even though i can see the text that i am testing for in the failing screenshot- my test is listed below

```
<?php
include('setupclass.php');
class AddNewPicStationTest extends setupclass
{


    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testMyTestCase()
    {
        $this->open($this->apppath);
        $this->click("css=a > img");
        $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        $this->type("name=username", "");
        $this->type("name=password", "");
        $this->click("name=submit");
        $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        $this->click("link=ADD LIKESTATION");
        $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        $this->click("link=HOME");
        $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        $this->click("link=ADD PICSTATION");
        $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        $this->type("id=title", "Test title 2");
        $this->type("id=message", "test description 2");
        $this->click("id=tip5");
        $this->type("id=album_title", "test album title 2");
        $this->type("id=album_description", "test album description 2");
        $this->click("//input[@value='Login']");
        $this->click("xpath=(//input[@name='group1'])[2]");
        $this->type("name=station_pic_upload", "C:\\Users\\chris laptop\\Desktop\\Logo.png");
        $this->click("name=g");
        $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");

        **$this->assertTrue($this->isTextPresent("Test title 2"),"object created");**
        $this->assertFalse($this->isTextPresent("Error"),"Error is present");
        $this->assertFalse($this->isTextPresent("Profiler"),"PRofiler is running");

        $this->click("link=LOGOUT");
        $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    }
}
?>
```

the asterisk line fails even though it is present in the screen grab.. i am new to this and any help would be appreciated

this is my page below that the test is looking for- STATION TITLE

```
<table width="620px" align="left" style="text-align:left;">
        <tr style="font-weight:bold;background-color:#f1f1f1">
            <td colspan="5" STYLE="text-align:center;font-weight:bold">FACEBOOK PIC STATIONS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="font-weight:bold;background-color:#f1f1f1">
            <td width="15%">STATION ID</td>
            <td width="50%">STATION TITLE</td>
            <td width="10%">STATION STATS</td>
            <td width="15%">LAST POST</td>
            <td width="10%"></td>

        </tr>
        <?foreach($picstations->result() as $row){?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=anchor('socialmedia/edit_picstation/'.$row->station_id,$row->station_id);?> </td>
                <td><?=anchor('socialmedia/edit_picstation/'.$row->station_id,$row->title);?> </td>
                <td><?=anchor('stats/home/station_stats/'.$row->station_id,'STATS');?> </td>
                <td><?=$this->upd8r_date->get_last_post_from_station_time($row->station_id)?></td>
                <td><?=anchor('socialmedia/delete/'.$row->station_id,'delete');?></td>
            </tr>
        <?}?>
    </table>
```

and heres my phpunit output-

```
1) AddNewPicStationTest::testMyTestCase
Current URL: http://localhost/upd8r_new/socialmedia/add_picstation
Screenshot: http://localhost/upd8r_new/tests/screenshots/692eb179f8146d2a8491442
68dd2a99a.png

object created
Failed asserting that false is true.

C:\xampplite\php\phpunit:46

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Errors: 1.
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the assertion which failed? Also, are you sure the text matches exactly (no invisible characters or whatever)?

Comment: i assumed that since it fails after the "object created" text that it is the one that fails.

Comment: my bad, did not notice the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to add some closure- if you looking at this question and struggling with the same issue- I'm using selenium and phpunit on windows 7.

Altering `waitForPageToload(1)` wasn't doing anything so I added `sleep(1);` to the code and this allowed the tests to run and pass correctly

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which PHP bindings you use, but the usual thing to do is this (pseudocode):

```
// if element is NOT present, try to wait a little more until timeout
var targetTime = currentTime() + 5000; // 5 seconds from now
while(currentTime() < targetTime) {
    if (!isElementPresent("someLocator")) {
        wait(250);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

That's because your element is likely to be loaded asynchronously (via AJAX) and `waitForPageToLoad()` can't know that's happening. It simply thinks the page is completely loaded the whole time. See whether your bindings have a method called `waitForElementPresent()` or similar. Otherwise, implements the method above.

By the way, Selenium 2 (WebDriver) has [Implicit wait](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#implicit-waits) option to do this for you automatically. If any element is not found, it will try to look for it for the specified time before throwing an exception.

---

The other thing that can be wrong is that the looked up text is actually hidden in an `<iframe>` element. If that is the case, you need to select the right frame.

Comment: its not loaded through ajax/js its just a normal php echo in a table- i will update the question witht he code i am using

Comment: Um. Weird. However, it is after a page load, so I still suspect that load as a cause of this - they sometimes act devilishly. Try waiting a little more - or try asserting anything else to see if anything works. Anyway, I added the second most common cause of this problem to my answer.

Comment: i added sleep(1); after each assertion and the assertions pass correctly... altering waitForPageToLoad had no real affect